# MySQL: How to get rows repeated x times

Tags: php, mysql

Which MySQL query should I use to get just rows repeated X times?

Example (stupid one ^^):

```
John likes apples.
Dave likes apples.
Bough likes bananas.
Light likes apples.
Wiky likes bananas.
```

I want a query that returns just fruits liked by 3 people (apples in my example).
Cheers!

Comment: I've been dying to know this one -- all I have is hacks, I'd like to see a real answer.

Comment: What you mean by "just rows repeated X times?"

Comment: Could you please give us an example of what you consider a repeated row?

Comment: How many rows, and why do want them to be repeated.

Comment: Yes, please give an example.  The question is unclear.

Comment: Voting to close.   Don't play guessing game. Elaborate your quesiton.

Comment: @Harry Joy, no, I am serious, it's legitimate that post been auclear and you ask to clarify the question, where's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want a query that returns just
>   fruits liked by 3 people (apples in my
>   example)

Try this:

```
SELECT fruit_name FROM `table` group by fruit_name having count(fruit_name)>=3;
```

Comment: Great Harry Joy, here is a person who helps! thanks, You solved it!

Comment: @Nadj: you are always welcome. But next time ask questions with proper and clear description.

Answer (score 2):

if "address" is the column by which you define if 2 rows are the same, then:

```
select address, count(address) as cnt from mailing_list group by address having cnt = $x order by cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to count each repeated row of a column:

```
select count(*), column1 from table group by column
```

Specify "column" as the column you want to know if it's repeated.  If you want to see if more than one column is repeated, separate with commas.

```
select count(*), column1, column2 from table group by column1,column2
```

EDIT:

And if you want to get just rows with X repeats:

```
select c, column1 from (select count(*) as c, column1 from table group by column1) where c = X
```